# Add ClaimsIdentity to ClaimsPrincipal - JwtBearer

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity

My system consists of two authorization steps (but not the standard way).

My client application first connects with server passing login and password (it's just something like ApiSecret and ApiKey).

Next, after authentication, server returns bearer token with basic info (username, roles etc). But notice that this user is like ApiClient not a living person :)

Next, application shows login form. And this is time for a living person to login. So he passes his credentials to API which checks whether this user can be logged in.

And this is the place that I have problem with. Until now I thought it would be work like that:

If the user can be logged to the application, I create new ClaimsIdentity and ADD it to ClaimsPrincipal Identities.

The idea is great but it doesn't work :/ It turns out that next requests don't send this second identity information. I even know why. Becase ClaimsPrincipal is created based on received bearer token. But this knowledge doesn't solve my problem.

What should I do to add new ClaimsIdentity to existing ClaimsPrincipal and store this value between requests? (until user logges out of the application)

Comment: I don't undestand your architecture. How does your app communicate with the client? (user) - ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Issue another bearer token?

Comment: It's a bit hard to visualize what you are trying to do. Post code, post relevant framework versions (WebApi? EF Identity?). Are you saying that you want two parallel identities at the same time, or do you want to replace the first one (api user vs physical user)? Sounds like you are overcomplicating things, which is rarely a good idea when it comes to authentication / authorization

Comment: I am using WebApi and EF Identity. I just have something like 2 users - the first one is api client - you can say that this user is the client application which "logs in" to WebApi. The other user is a human who logs in to client application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging and research I was able to create a solution (.Net Core 2). 
You have to add Cookie Authentication in configure services and all of this should look like that:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                 //standard settings
            })
            .AddCookie(AuthTypes.CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE, cfg =>
                {
                    //cookie settings; the most important is following event:
                    cfg.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = (CookieValidatePrincipalContext ctx) =>
                    {
                        ClaimsPrincipal mainUser = ctx.HttpContext.User; //get ClaimsPrincipal from JwtBearer
                        ClaimsPrincipal cookieUser = ctx.Principal; //get ClaimsPrincipal read from Cookie

                        Debug.Assert(mainUser.Identities.Count() == 1);

                        //now we have to add ClaimsIdentity to main ClaimsPrincipal (from JwtBearer). We add only those absent in main ClaimsPrincipal (here is simplified solution) 
                        var claimsToAdd = cookieUser.Identities.Where(id => id.AuthenticationType != mainUser.Identities.ElementAt(0).AuthenticationType);
                        mainUser.AddIdentities(claimsToAdd);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                }

            );
```

AuthTypes.CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE - it's just string with your authentication type name.

Next we have to configure default policy filter later on in ConfigureServices (basic configuration):

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, AuthTypes.CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE })
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
});
```

What's important here is to pass this array in AuthorizationPolicyBuilder.

Now Authorization will take under consideration JwtBearer, but cookie will also be read.

And now how to set the cookie at all. This can be additional login process (you do it at the controller level):

```
var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = true,
    IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(AuthTypes.CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE, User, authProps);
```

**User** here is just ClaimsPrincipal with additional ClaimsIdentities. 
And that's all folks :)